# How to create a stacked graph using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, graph, charts, chart.js

As of now I have successfully created a line graph using ChartJS. But I want to make it stacked graph.

Below is what I have till now:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone)
{
    var fifthSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        template: _.template($('#myChart5-template').html()),

        render: function(){
          $(this.el).html(this.template());
          var ctx = this.$el.find('#lineChart5')[0];
          var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
              datasets: [{
                label: "Unavailable Unit",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                data: this.model.attributes.unavailThisYear
              }, {
                label: "Vacant Unit",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.3)",
                borderColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.70)",
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.70)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.70)",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                data: this.model.attributes.vacThisYear 
              }]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Income in $'
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          });
        },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log("In the initialize function");
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
            this.render();
        }   
    });

    return fifthSubViewModel;
});
```

Currently, I am getting two line graph on a single chart. But I somehow want to make them stacked. I mean the second line graph starting point should be the place from where the first line graph. So, the area should not overlap. Is there any way I can tell that to my line chart to start from the value where the other line chart is ending so as to get a stacked graph.

**Current Screenshot not stacked:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting stacked: true next to your scaleLabel property?

Comment: No. I am new to all this so I don't know about it.

Comment: Shall I put scaleLabel : true in both line chart configuration? Kindly guide

Comment: Well, documentation says you should put  yAxes: [{
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Income in $'
                  }, 
                 stacked: true
                }]     . Not sure what display would that make

Comment: Do you mind pointing me to the link. I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-stacked-charts

Comment: Actually what you told was bang on. If you have some time you can put that as an answer and I will accept it. it will be useful for other SO users. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs of latest chartjs version, you need to set the stacked property to true in the axis you want to stack them. So in your case it would be:

```
       options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Income in $'
              },
              stacked: true
            }]
          }
        }
```

For more information go to [ChartJs Docs](http://chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-stacked-charts)

Comment: One small doubt. I am getting stacked graph now. I mean the values are properly getting appended and 2nd line chart is appending the value to the 1st line chart. Only problem is that the graph is kind of transparent. I mean suppose I give blue colour to 1st line chart and red to 2nd line chart. So I want to see two distinct colours for both line chart.

Comment: But in the bottom area (I mean the common one) which after stacking should only belong to the 1st graph. The colour is getting overlapped. Are you getting what I am saying? Kindly guide me. Many thanks!

Comment: I want to see separate "blue" in bottom shaded area and "red" in the above stacked area which standalone belongs to the 2nd line chart. But I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: I had to change the opacity and everything works fine now. Thank you once again. :)